# Does php-cli even exist in command line options?

Tags: php, command-line, shell-exec

I was trying to execute a php file thorugh php with shell_exec, this was the code:

```
$ex="php -f ".rtrim(dirname(__FILE__))."/sendmail.php";
if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows")
    pclose(popen("start /B ".$ex,"r")); 
else
    shell_exec($ex." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

The problem is that it didn't work on my server(I have even tried without the `-f`), but this is ok:

```
$ex="php-cli ".rtrim(dirname(__FILE__))."/sendmail.php";
if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows")
    pclose(popen("start /B ".$ex,"r"));
else
    shell_exec($ex." > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");
```

Can somebody tell me why it works? Does php-cli even exists?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like your site has simply renamed `php` to `php-cli`.

Comment: I have found this page: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuration of PHP on their site.

Comment: I'm not sure, because I my question was if php-cli is a real option or if the server interpretate it in some correct way, also I have seen that another server( in this case personal) that uses this code. Also php-cli was just a casual

Comment: `popen()` simply runs the command as a shell command. The server doesn't re-interpret it.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what will change?

Comment: What will change when? I don't understand your question, because I never said anything would change.

Comment: Sorry, why should I use popen() instead of shell_exec?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use popen() in this case, but I haven't researched it.

Comment: Ok, however I have changed php-cli with php5-cli, apparantly CPanel uses this comand as part of the debian package

Answer (score 0):

OS doesn't matter. You should be able to use `shell_exec` if it's not disabled in your `php.ini`

Comment: PHP doesn't throw any error, also exec return an empty array, and shell_exec log return the HTML header and no other information